# MS Access open a form to a specific id

Tags: forms, ms-access

I have a table which has 5 forms (form1, form2, form3, form4, form5). What I want to do is open a form to a specific record based on the id of the previous form. So say I open form1 with a record id of 15, I want to click a button which opens form2 to record id 15. By record id, I mean the ID in the main table. I am using the code below but it keeps opening form2 to a new record instead of the same record id as form1. Can anyone help please ?

```
Private Sub Command110_Click()
Dim recordID As Integer

   recordID = Me.ID
   MsgBox (recordID)

   DoCmd.OpenForm "Form2", , , "ID = " & recordID

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If by recordID, you mean the record number that is shown at the bottom of the screen, it is not going to work. You need to use a field name, so :

```
 DoCmd.OpenForm "Form2", , , "ID = " & AFieldThatMatchesID
```

To test, you can use a number that you are sure is an ID in form2:

```
 DoCmd.OpenForm "Form2", , , "ID = " & 7
```

You will save to save a new record before you try to open the next form:

```
 Me.Dirty = False
```

Comment: Yes that works when the id field is set , but when i open form 1 to a new record it doesn't seem to work, i dont know why this is because once you add data in the form it give the id an value, any ideas how i can get around this ?

Comment: How can a form open to a value that does not exist? You must save the record on form1 -- `Me.Dirty=False` -- before you open form2. I suspect you have got yourself into a tangled design ans that you should be thinking about subforms.

Comment: yes i had to save form1 first then open it works fine now thanks